# dotnetbrowser c# help remove entire div

Tags: c#, dotnetbrowser

I am using TeamDev Dotnetbrowser, for a tests, so how can I remove entire div, without a id, just using classname, for example:

```
<div class="home modulo-testbar"><a href="http://somelink" id="who" title="hohoho">test</a></p></div>
```

I hope someone could help me, please!

Regards.

Learning documentation, I found a way to "hide", but I still like remove entire div content.

I have created and used this code:

```
      DOMDocument document = e.Browser.GetDocument();
      List<DOMNode> divs = document.GetElementsByTagName("div");
           foreach (DOMNode node in divs)
             {
                 DOMElement element = node as DOMElement;
                    if (element.GetAttribute("class").ToLower().Contains("home modulo-testbar"))
                    {
                        element.SetAttribute("style","display:none");
                    }
             }
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

From looking at DOMNode API [docs](https://www.teamdev.com/downloads/dotnetbrowser/api/interface_dot_net_browser_1_1_d_o_m_1_1_d_o_m_node.html), this seems like it should remove a node from its parent:

```
var parent = node.Parent;
if(parent != null) {
    parent.removeChild(node);
}
```

Put the above code where you currently set the style attribute to hide the element.

Comment: Thankyou. Work like a charm! ;)

Comment: Great to hear it!  Can you please accept the answer?